Can I update the dataset in a PowerBI report that has already been published while still retaining the same 'link' to access the report?
I make this monthly report which I have published for the month of February. Now I need to update the same report with data for March (this is not a live data report as someone has to send me this data in a spreadsheet every month). I was asked to see if the link used to access the February data could still be used to access the report once I updated the report with March data.
I see that on the web viewer of the PowerBI report I can only make minor edits. Is it any way possible to change the data set (in this case adding the new spreadsheet with March's data) and still be able access via the same link as the report I published earlier?
I tried editing on the web viewer but I don't see any ways to upload a new dataset unless I go through the Desktop app.
